# muliple website and same desnign but different domain and colors and logo

Tags: magento2

**I want to create two websites in the same backend but different domains but the same design and  logo and colors different**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with magneto:
Steps to do this:

1. create multi websites from admin first.
2. use default setting for design in both websites.
3. create domain and point it to same directory.
4. use index.php from pub folder to load website according to domain.

Comment: can change logo and colors in website 2 but not change in website one?

Comment: or copy all folder app and pub and var and lib  in folder (website two ) and index.php diffrent  ? this method correct ?